# Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation. Tree was nullptr. If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued

Tags: c++, tree, sum, nodes

I'm trying to get the sum of all integers in a tree, C++, but whenever I run the program it keeps breaking with this error:

Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation. Tree was nullptr. If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued

This is my function:

```
int sigma(Node<int> *Tree)
{
    int sum = 0;
    if (Tree->item == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        sum = sum + sigma(Tree->left);
        sum = Tree->item;
        sum = sum + sigma(Tree->right);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This is my header file:

```
template <typename T>
class Node
{
public:
    Node(T itm, Node *lft, Node* rht);
    Node(T itm); // for creating a leaf node 
    ~Node();
    void printTree();
    bool searchTree(T key);
    bool search(T word);
    int depth(Node *tree);
    T item;
    Node *left, *right;
};

template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(T itm)
{
    item = itm;
    left = nullptr;
    right = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(T itm, Node *lft, Node *rht)
{
    left = lft;
    right = rht;
    item = itm;

}

template <typename T>
Node<T>::~Node()
{
    delete[] left, right;
}
```

anyone any ideas on how i could fix this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: You already have the answer: *Tree was nullptr*

Comment: `delete[] left, right;` I have never seen this (and I will never use it).  Does this actually delete all entries? If not, it just deletes left and the ,-operator does nothing.

Comment: Also `sum = Tree->item;` overwrites whatever `sum = sum + sigma(Tree->left);` wrote in sum, just switch the lines

Comment: Yes figure that out when I then debugged through it!! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add check Tree == NULL at beginning

```
int sigma(Node<int> *Tree)
{
    int sum = 0;
    if (Tree == NULL || Tree->item == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        sum = sum + sigma(Tree->left);
        sum = sum + Tree->item;
        sum = sum + sigma(Tree->right);
    }
    return sum;
}
```